# Adding a new participant status

Tags: civievent

I keep trying to add a new participant status, but the page isn't letting me. I hit save, but nothing happens. I thought it was my browser, so I switched. I thought maybe a bug, so I upgraded to the latest CiviCRM. Still can't save it. I've tried clicking on Save as well as just hitting Enter when in one of the fields. Nothing.

Drupal 7, CiviCRM 5.27.0

Console shows the following error:

```
An invalid form control with name='visibility_id' is not focusable
```

Comment: Does the browser console show any javascript errors? If you turn off popup forms at administer - customize - display preferences so that the form is its own whole page does it then work?

Comment: It's already in its own page, not a pop-up. I'll go see if any errors are popping up.

Comment: An invalid form control with name='visibility_id' is not focusable.

Comment: What CMS/version? I'm not seeing that warning/error with either firefox or chrome on drupal/master. Not sure if that particular error is important, but maybe something's not loading.

Comment: Drupal 7, CiviCRM 5.27.0

Comment: Hmm, not seeing the problem there either. Not sure what to suggest further for troubleshooting other than the usual - disable extensions, see if switching to standard bartik theme helps, etc.

Comment: I don't have much by the way of extensions on, and nothing that should affect this page. I'm using Seven, which is a pretty heavily used Admin theme. Switching to Bartik doesn't change it. I didn't expect it would since it's a form error.

Comment: Have you tried doing the same at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - I didn't have a Visibility selected. There isn't an asterisk next to it letting you know it is required and no error pops up telling you that you need to choose a visibility. So it is indeed a CiviCRM issue - it's missing the asterisk and a message letting you know that you need to choose one.